# C# - Socket router for passing sockets to multiple socket servers

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking

is it possible to have one socket router that would pass incoming sockets to socket servers?
I need this because I want to have multiple servers for handling sockets but only one port for clients to connect to. so if one of the servers goes down, router would send the socket to other healthy socket servers.
Is this even possible and how? or any other solution for my problem?

Comment: Are you looking for a load balancer?

Comment: @CodeCaster I was more looking for a mechanism to route sockets to other servers but load balancer might be working too, is there an article, code sample or ... that I can chekout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is definitely possible, and is used very widespread.

Basically you need to have one TCP server running on that one port you  want clients to connect to. Then you can listen for connections. When a connection is established you can reroute packets to other servers (you choose).

1. Listen on a port with your main server
2. Accept connections as they come in.
3. When a connection is opened, read the data in another thread. Take that data and send it to the other server you want to.

Basically, it is a proxy.

Comment: OK, but is the socket is still connected to the main server, but isn't it better to route the connection to another server? and how can I do either of them cause there doesn't seem to be any article or books on this topic

Comment: True you can reroute the connection by telling the client which address to connect to. In fact, that would probably be easier to implement. As for articles and books I don't have any suggestions. I have done some work on a java based proxy for the game Minecraft, however it is **unfinished and kind of messy**. Nonetheless, if you want to look at it, it's [here](https://github.com/jython234/BouncyBall).

Comment: OK, I'm gonna edit your answer a little bit and make it as the right answer. but just a quick question, by telling client which address, you mean giving the IP and port to connect to?

Comment: Yes, because you dont want a proxy.